Ergonomic loop splitting
I am looking for a more ergonomic way to do loop splitting in C++.
Motivating example
Imagine we want to blur all the rows of an image by convolving each row with the well-known {1, 4, 6, 4, 1} filter kernel. The first and last two pixels of each row have to be handled separately, because otherwise we would access out-of-bounds pixels. Here is a diagram:

Unfortunately, those boundary checks inhibit compiler optimization, so instead of writing a single loop with boundary checks (see blur_rows1 below for reference), we have to split up the loop into three separate loops (see function blur_rows2):

one loop over the first two pixels,
one loop over the middle pixels which does most of the work and does not require any boundary checks, and
one loop over the last two pixels:

// Blur row with loop splitting.
for (int x =           0; x <      radius; x++) blur(dst, src, nx, ny, x, y, kernel, radius);
for (int x =      radius; x < nx - radius; x++) blur(dst, src, nx, ny, x, y, kernel, radius);
for (int x = nx - radius; x < nx         ; x++) blur(dst, src, nx, ny, x, y, kernel, radius);

This makes blur_rows2 roughly 10 times faster than blur_rows1 (50 µs vs 500 µs for a 512x512 image).
Flawed solutions
There are multiple ways to implement loop splitting, which all have various flaws:

Implement the inner-most loop body as a function like shown below. Disadvantages:

Can't read code from top to bottom because inner loop is implemented as a function somewhere else (bad code locality).
Insanely large parameter lists.
Relies on compiler to inline the function (e.g. __attribute__((always_inline)) with GCC)
Relies on compiler to recognize that boundary checks can be removed in middle loop.


Implement inner-most loop body as a macro.

Also suffers from lack of code locality.
Also has to rely on compiler optimization.
Have to add \ after every line.
The usual disadvantages of macros (compiler errors become incomprehensible, code becomes harder to read and more difficult to reason about).


Pad src with boundary fill values so boundary check is not required.

Increases memory requirements.
Increases memory bandwidth cost.


https://github.com/halide/Halide

Difficult to learn.
Rarely compiles.



Question
It would be nice if there was compiler support for something like #pragma loop split (0, radius, nx - radius, nx) or, even better, some way to tell the compiler that it should split the loop such that the condition if (0 <= x2 && x2 < nx) goes away.
Is there something like this? I feel like it might be possible with some clever tricks like Duff's device or template magic. Solutions that only work with GCC or Clang are fine.
Example code for loop splitting
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using std::uint8_t;

const uint32_t kernel[5] = {1, 4, 6, 4, 1};
const int radius = 2;

// Blur the pixel at (x, y) from src image of size (nx, ny) and write to dst image of same size
static inline void blur(std::vector<uint8_t> &dst, const std::vector<uint8_t> &src, int nx, int x, int y, const uint32_t *kernel, int radius){
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    for (int x2 = x - radius; x2 <= x + radius; x2++){
        // Only sum pixels within image boundaries.
        // The compiler is smart enough to remove the branch, but only when doing manual loop splitting.
        if (0 <= x2 && x2 < nx){
            sum += kernel[x2 - x + radius] * src[y * nx + x2];
        }
    }
    dst[y * nx + x] = sum / 16;
}

void blur_rows1(std::vector<uint8_t> &dst, const std::vector<uint8_t> &src, int nx, int ny){
    for (int y = 0; y < ny; y++){
        // Blur row without loop splitting.
        for (int x = 0; x < nx; x++){
            blur(dst, src, nx, x, y, kernel, radius);
        }
    }
}

void blur_rows2(std::vector<uint8_t> &dst, const std::vector<uint8_t> &src, int nx, int ny){
    for (int y = 0; y < ny; y++){
        // Blur row with loop splitting.
        for (int x =           0; x <      radius; x++) blur(dst, src, nx, x, y, kernel, radius);
        for (int x =      radius; x < nx - radius; x++) blur(dst, src, nx, x, y, kernel, radius);
        for (int x = nx - radius; x < nx         ; x++) blur(dst, src, nx, x, y, kernel, radius);
    }
}

double sec(){
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<duration<double>>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

int main(){
    int nx = 512;
    int ny = 512;
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> src(nx * ny);
    std::vector<uint8_t> dst1(nx * ny);
    std::vector<uint8_t> dst2(nx * ny);

    // Initialize src images.
    for (int i = 0; i < nx * ny; i++){
        src[i] = std::rand() & 0xff;
    }

    // Run benchmark 10 times.
    for (int i_run = 0; i_run < 10; i_run++){
        double t0 = sec();

        blur_rows1(dst1, src, nx, ny);

        double t1 = sec();

        blur_rows2(dst2, src, nx, ny);

        double t2 = sec();

        std::cout << "blur_rows1: " << (t1 - t0) * 1e6 << " µs" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "blur_rows2: " << (t2 - t1) * 1e6 << " µs" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // Check that result is correct.
        for (int i = 0; i < nx * ny; i++){
            if (dst1[i] != dst2[i]) std::exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


A lambda would solve the code locality problem

C and C++ are two very different languages. Please tag only the actual language you will be working in. Please take some time to read the C++ or the C tag wikis, especially the sections labeled "Using c and c++ together".

@AlanBirtles Good idea, but it seems that both GCC and Clang seem to be unable to inline a lambda function, which would make them unsuitable for performance optimization.

@Someprogrammerdude It does not matter to me whether the solution to my problem is C or C++. Both would work for me, even if it should not be possible in the other language. As far as I can tell, this case is not covered by the Wiki. Should I post the question twice with two different tags?

If both work for your then pick a higher level language.

@BlueSky They (clang/gcc) should be able too inline lambdas, what are your compiler flags. (Optimization should be on). Consider adding guard borders around your input data (so you will always be in bounds even if the kernel slides over the edges). You can consider mirroring the original edges into the guard border (the convolution near the edege will be incorrect in any case anyway)

I wouldn't worry much about the readability of the first approach. Even when you're not splitting the loop, it's often a good idea to put the body in a separate function to keep it short. Naming the function provides an abstraction that makes it easier to understand.

@3CxEZiVlQ Okay, I'll go with C++ then.

@PepijnKramer My compiler flags are -march=native -O3. Did you actually test whether GCC or Clang can optimize a lambda in this case or is it just a guess? Regarding your suggestion of guard borders; this wastes performance due to memory bandwidth (see point 3 in my question).

I know, but in the end the best optimization will be quite hardware dependent too. E.g. trade a little memory bandwidth for less branches (missed branch predictions are expensive). Anyway for optimization issues like this I would not start asking questions, but really understand the hardware I am on...  and then use a profiler and chip away at bottlnecks for my system.
